# using ternary operation instead of if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, operation, ternary

I want to do this code you have seen using ternary operation instead of if conditional blocks. Generally, is the use of the ternary operator always a good choice? In some places they say it is more readable and more flexible code to use the ternary operator instead of constantly using if conditional blocks.

```
     @Override
public ResponseEntity<? extends UserDetailResponse> getByPhoneNumberUserDetail(String phoneNumber) {
    UserDetail userDetail = userDetailRepository.findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    if (!userDetail.getPhoneNumber().equals(phoneNumber)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserDetailResponse(MessageCase.COULDNT_FOUNDED_USER_DETAILS_SUCH_PHONE_NUMBER.getMessage(), 400), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserDetailResponse(MessageCase.USER_DETAL_SUCESSFULLY_FOUNDED.getMessage(), 200), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't appear to make much sense. Why do you have to check the phone again when you asked the `userDetailRepository` to give you a user with that phone already? Why would that condition `!userDetail.getPhoneNumber().equals(phoneNumber)` ever be true?

Comment: Firstly Checking if such a number exists in the database is the best choice for me.

Comment: What I mean is that if `userDetail` is non-null then it should mean the phone matched, so you shouldn't have to check it again...

Comment: I understand what you mean, I will make changes, but now I'm wondering if I can do this using a ternary operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UserDetailResponse userDetailResponse = userDetail!=null && !userDetail.getPhoneNumber().equals(phoneNumber)  ? new UserDetailResponse(MessageCase.COULDNT_FOUNDED_USER_DETAILS_SUCH_PHONE_NUMBER.getMessage(), 400) : new UserDetailResponse(MessageCase.USER_DETAL_SUCESSFULLY_FOUNDED.getMessage(), 200);
responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(UserDetailResponse,UserDetailResponse.getStatus());
return responseEntity;
```

Implement getStatus in UserDetailResponse to fetch status code.

Comment: sorry, but didn't work

Comment: what is the issue/error? Have updated few things.Try again

Comment: I have not any idea, there are many problem. Could you rather do it?

Comment: Again I did edit, it worked.!